# WPF LocalizationExtensionComboBox locBinding NullReference Exception OnPropertyChanged of View (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, localization, nullreferenceexception

i got a ViewModelMain where i am changin my current Views and current ViewModels.

```
        public ViewModelBase CurrentVm { get; set; }

        public UserControl Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
            set
            {
                _content = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Content);  // this is the Line where i get the Exception
            }
        }
```

the problem occurs when i am navigating from one specific View with a LocBinding to another without one..

In the current View i have an locBinding with an Combobox

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="45" MaxWidth="80" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AmountUnits.View}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameResourceKeyTextBoxItemTemplate}" />
```

Item Template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NameResourceKeyTextBoxItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <lex:LocExtension x:Key="LocalizedHeader" x:Name="LocalizedHeader"/>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Engine:LocBinding Source="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Target="{x:Reference LocalizedHeader}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Reference LocalizedHeader}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

the Property of the Binding (in my ViewModel):

```
        private CollectionViewSource _amountUnits;
        public CollectionViewSource AmountUnits
        {
            get { return _amountUnits; }
            set { _amountUnits = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => AmountUnits);
            }
        }

        AmountUnits.Source =
                    AmountUnit.GetAll().Select(x => new MaterialInputProp(x.Id, x.TransKey)
                        {
                            Name = x.TransKey,
                            IsSelected = x.IsSelected
                        }).ToList();
```

this works all just fine... though when i am changing my View in my ViewModelMain and PropertyChanged of my current View is Raised i get an NullReferenceException.. :/ 
It doesnt care if my new ViewModel is empty or complex... when i am changin my UserControl Content i get the Exception.. :/

eg. how i change my View in my ViewModelMain

```
CurrentVm = new MaterialInputViewModel(mc.NewValue);
Content = new InputView();
```

in the Setter of Content it breaks...

the StackTrace:

```
at WPFLocalizeExtension.Engine.LocBinding.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnDataContextChanged(DependencyObject contextElement)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
...
```

if you need more information please just ask... i need help! its urgent... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my issue...

an update of my localization extension to version 2.1.2 fixed it... 
had the latest stable version of 1.x.x before